# Ubuntu 11.04 can't login after fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, login

So i just installed ubuntu server 11.04 and after i rebooted i'm seeing a cli interface asking for my :

> Ubuntu 11.04 new-host tty1
>
> new-host login:
>
> Password:

i've tried entering the user name and password i specified when i did the install but that did not work. The password looks fine if i enter it into the login field so i d

Comment: So you may have flubbed it during the install.  You have 2 choices.  Re-install or perform a password recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has gone wrong during installation.
The fast thing to do is boot computer from DVD with linux, mount root filesystem, chroot to it, and change password/create users using `passwd` and adduser or just edit `/etc/passwd`.
Probably also host name should be changed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you know the format of `/etc/shadow`, you can simply delete the password from it for your login.  Boot to a LiveCD, mount your `/` filesystem, edit `/etc/shadow`, delete the second field of your login.  The delimiter is a colon.  As per `man 5 shadow`:

> This field may be empty, in which case no passwords are required to
>   authenticate as the specified login name. However, some applications
>   which read the /etc/shadow file may decide not to permit any access at
>   all if the password field is empty.

At this point, boot normally and you no longer have a password requirement.  Feel free to reset it with `passwd`

Comment: This reminds me of a computer security saying.  "If someone has physical access to your data, it is no longer your data."

Answer (score -1):

I had to try to login with the username/password several times...
Eventually it started to work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Well... okay sorry.
I had the same problem... after some attempts it started to work.

Comment: That's fine, but this isn't really an answer, it's a comment.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue, but I was using vmware workstation 9 and the VM after reboot just display these questions. I solved the problem with the creation of a new VM, but after to the first run I delete a CD-DVD (autoins) from the hardware list of my VM.